# Vaadin Split Layout Listener - div width from client side

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to get current (on client side) div width after the user has stopped resizing the Vaadin Split Layout with drag and drop?

Something like this?

```
splitLayout.addSplitterDragendListener(new ComponentEventListener<GeneratedVaadinSplitLayout.SplitterDragendEvent<SplitLayout>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComponentEvent(GeneratedVaadinSplitLayout.SplitterDragendEvent<SplitLayout> splitLayoutSplitterDragendEvent) {
            
            Notification.show(div.getWidth()); //it's return width which was defined on compilation

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This is currently [a documented missing feature](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-split-layout/issues/152) in SplitLayout Java API.

In Vaadin there bottom layer Element API, which has a generic client side event listener. It is possible to utilize that to listen the dragend event and get the size of the primary and secondary panel.

```
getElement().addEventListener("splitter-dragend", e -> {
  this.primarySizePixel = e.getEventData().getNumber(PRIMARY_SIZE);
  this.secondarySizePixel = e.getEventData().getNumber(SECONDARY_SIZE);

  double totalSize = this.primarySizePixel + this.secondarySizePixel;
  this.splitterPosition = Math.round((this.primarySizePixel / totalSize) * 100.0);
})
    .addEventData(PRIMARY_SIZE)
    .addEventData(SECONDARY_SIZE);
```

Here `PRIMARY_SIZE` is either `"element._primaryChild.offsetHeight"` or `"element._primaryChild.offsetWidth"` depending on the orientation, and `SECONDARY_SIZE` `"element._secondaryChild.offsetHeight"` or `"element._secondaryChild.offsetWidth"` respectively.

There is complete class extending SplitLayout with this solution documented in Vaadin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-split-layout/issues/152#issuecomment-634612231).

Btw. using event listeners with Vaadin Java API is much more concise by using Lambdas instead of anonymous classes.