# Horizontal split panel - To get width in pixels

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Can we get width of the horizontal split panel in pixels. Also to get the width of individual right and left side width in a split panel?

Comment: Depending on your exact needs, you might also find this (and the github issue linked from there) useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462505/vaadin-split-layout-listener-div-width-from-client-side

Comment: Marc: That's for newer Vaadin versions, though. Vaadin 8 has a different implementation.

Comment: Absolutely, sorry for the confusion! In my defence... I have nothing, that "8" is pretty prominent :-\

Answer (score 1):

The SizeReporter add-on allows you to get the pixel sizes of any Component in the UI: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/sizereporter. If you add a split position change listener to the HorizontalSplitPanel, you can get the split position and unit from the event; if the unit is "%", calculating the pixel size from the size of the parent should be a matter of a simple calculation.